# wordpress add_action, do_action

Tags: php, wordpress

Почему это работает

```
add_action('my_hook_test', 'my_hook_func', 10, 1 );
do_action('my_hook_test', 'test');

function my_hook_func($title){
    print_r($title);
}
```

А вот это не работает

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_hook_func', 10, 1 );
do_action('admin_menu', 'test');

function my_hook_func($title){
    print_r($title);
}
```

Как применить do_action на admin_menu

Answer (score 0):

Они работают обе. На пустой странице фронтенда их видно. В бэкенде их вывод не видно, потому что он перекрыт стилями. Откройте исходный код страницы - увидите.

У вас какая задача? Вывести что-то перед началом вывода меню? Ядро вызывает такое действие: `do_action( 'admin_menu', '' );`. Поэтому, если в вашем коде присутствует только `add_action('admin_menu', 'my_hook_func', 10, 1 );`, то ваш print_r выводит пустую строку в этот момент.

Для теста используйте код

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu');

function my_admin_menu( $title ) {
    echo '************************';
}
```

Откройте исходный код страницы (Ctrl+U), увидите эти звёздочки.

На этом хуке обычно регистрируют страницу меню.